# Program throwing exception despite generic Exception e catch

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
public class TryCatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Score[] = {5,3,9};  //my array
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag=true; //boolean for the while loop that will keep on asking for input till the input is correct

    System.out.println("Enter index: ");

    int ind = sc.nextInt(); //taking input

    while(flag){
        try {
            System.out.println("Value at index is = " + Score[ind]);
            flag= false;      //if input is correct, the bool turns false and loop stops

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("Enter a valid value!");
            ind = sc.nextInt();  //should ask for input again if the input isn't right
        }
    }

}
}
```

So the problem I am having is that the catch block works for ArrayOutOfBound exception, but not when I enter some other character like a letter. What should I do?

UPDATE:

I fixed the bug by creating a new instance of the scanner class object in the catch block.

```
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the scanner class object again to close the previous scanner and dump all the input in it.

Add this line to the end of your catch block-

```
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are asking for integer input within the catch, which isn't handled anywhere else, try this:

```
int ind; //taking input

while(flag){
    try {
        find = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value at index is = " + Score[ind]);
        flag= false;      //if input is correct, the bool turns false and loop stops

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        System.out.println("Enter a valid value!");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after changing it and adding a continue keyword, it keeps on printing the statement infinitely when I enter a char or a string.
 
`while(flag){
            try {
                int ind = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Value at index is = " + Score[ind]);
                flag= false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a valid value!");
                continue;
            }
        } `

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the exception is thrown outside of the try block. You read from the keyboard either before the try-catch block or in the catch block.

Comment: Even after changing it and adding a continue keyword, it keeps on printing the statement infinitely when I enter a char or a string.
 
`while(flag){
            try {
                int ind = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Value at index is = " + Score[ind]);
                flag= false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a valid value!");
                continue;
            }
        } `

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown within a catch block that exception will not be caught. Also you need to clear the input with nextLine or you will get an infinite loop, the correct code would be as follows:

```
System.out.println("Enter index: ");

while (flag) {

    try {
        int ind = sc.nextInt(); //taking input
        System.out.println("Value at index is = " + Score[ind]);
        flag = false;      //if input is correct, the bool turns false and loop stops
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid value!");
        sc.nextLine();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need to separate the exceptions (when catching multiple types) with a pipe operator `(SQLException | IOException e)`
for example.